# поиск совпадений из двух массивов

Tags: javascript

Как мне найти совпадения в двух массивах?
задача такая: есть массив из jsona,

```
[{   
  "id": 112,
    "name": "Standart Room",
    "img": "rooms_img_1.jpg",
    "price": 126,
    "category": "single",
    "roomType": "room",
    "adults": 1,
    "children": 0,
    "bed": "King",
    "facilities": "Closet with hangers, HD flat-screen TV, Telephone",
    "area": 20,
    "breakfast": false,
    "reservedFrom": "2020-02-01T23:28:56.782Z",
    "reservedTo": "2020-02-05T23:28:56.782Z"
},  {
    "id": 313,
    "name": "Double Room",
    "img": "rooms_img_3.jpg",
    "price": 320,
    "category": "double",
    "roomType": "room",
    "adults": 2,
    "children": 1,
    "bed": "Twin",
    "facilities": "Closet with hangers, HD flat-screen TV, Telephone",
    "area": 20,
    "breakfast": false,
    "reservedFrom": "2020-03-07T23:28:56.782Z",
    "reservedTo": "2020-03-091T23:28:56.782Z"       
}]
```

и так далее. И другой массив, с перечнем типов комнат:

const roomCategories = ["single", "standart", "double", "family", "vip", "suite"];

Мне нужно пройтись по первому массиву искать по категориям и перебрать все типы комнат по одному из массива и создать новый по 1 типу комнат из каждой категории.

Я только начинаю учить JS и есть сложности(
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Приведите пример данных, которые должны получиться на выходе.

Comment: идея такая. что в каждой категории в джсоне есть куча комнат, н-р категория сингл - 50 комнат, категория дабл - 100 комнат и тд. Я не хочу выводить их все для пользователя после фильтрации, а только по 1 типу комнаты в каждой категории

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите пример данных, которые должны получиться на выходе. В  формате json.

Comment: Фильтр лучше делать на серверной стороне (Если это возможно).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let mas1 = [{   
  "id": 112,
    "name": "Standart Room",
    "img": "rooms_img_1.jpg",
    "price": 126,
    "category": "single",
    "roomType": "room",
    "adults": 1,
    "children": 0,
    "bed": "King",
    "facilities": "Closet with hangers, HD flat-screen TV, Telephone",
    "area": 20,
    "breakfast": false,
    "reservedFrom": "2020-02-01T23:28:56.782Z",
    "reservedTo": "2020-02-05T23:28:56.782Z"
}, {"id": 113,
    "name": "Standart Room",
    "img": "rooms_img_1.jpg",
    "price": 126,
    "category": "single",
    "roomType": "room",
    "adults": 1,
    "children": 0,
    "bed": "King",
    "facilities": "Closet with hangers, HD flat-screen TV, Telephone",
    "area": 20,
    "breakfast": false,
    "reservedFrom": "2020-02-01T23:28:56.782Z",
    "reservedTo": "2020-02-05T23:28:56.782Z"
}, {
    "id": 313,
    "name": "Double Room",
    "img": "rooms_img_3.jpg",
    "price": 320,
    "category": "double",
    "roomType": "room",
    "adults": 2,
    "children": 1,
    "bed": "Twin",
    "facilities": "Closet with hangers, HD flat-screen TV, Telephone",
    "area": 20,
    "breakfast": false,
    "reservedFrom": "2020-03-07T23:28:56.782Z",
    "reservedTo": "2020-03-091T23:28:56.782Z"       
}];

const roomCategories = ["single", "standart", "double", "family", "vip", "suite"];

// console.log(mas1)

let result = {};

roomCategories.forEach(category => {
  result[category] = mas1.filter(f => f.category === category);
});

console.log(result);
```

использую `filter` - он отбирает коллекцию по предикату.
`foreach` - цикл (перебор) массива.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Решила делать через find. roomCategories.forEach(category => {

                    let room = avaliableRooms.find(function(e){return e.category==category;});
                    resultRooms.push(room);
                });